# How to attach a new 2x4 wall frame's top plate to a concrete load bearing ceiling beam?

Tags: walls, wood, beam, frame

I have a concrete beam that extends throughout my apartment. The concrete beam comes down about 30cm from the ceiling. I would like to build a wall underneath the beam, running along the beam.

I plan to build the wall out of wood framing. I am wondering how best to make sure the wall is stable by attaching it to the ceiling. The wall will extend from one structural load bearing pillar to another load bearing pillar, running underneath, along the beam.

Is it safe to drill holes and put screws through the top plate and into the concrete beam?

How else could we make sure it's stable?

Thanks!

Comment: do you even have the permission to attach anything to the beam? ... your question is pointless if you do not have permission

Comment: To clarify, to most Americans (who do tend to answer a majority of questions here), "apartment" implies rental, not ownership, and usually renters are _not_ allowed to do this type of construction work in their apartment.

Comment: Apologies, was a little lost in translation. I actually own the condo and it is a property within a building with other apartments/condos above. I have all permissions required. I am just curious at the best approaches to tackling putting up a divider wall.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest TapCon concrete fasteners with washers.  They come with a disposable masonry drill bit for pre-drilling.  Use a hammer-drill.

Another option is powder actuated nails, but a concrete beam might be made from concrete that is too hard for PAT nails to penetrate.

Answer (score 1):

I would frame up your wall in such manner that you can elevate the top plate in place and hold it there by temporarily placing 2x4's on end under it. Before pushing that top plate in place apply beads of construction adhesive along its length. Use an adhesive that is recommended for wood and concrete use.

It the 2x4 struts are cut a bit longer than the height to the top plate they can be wedged into place to tightly force that adhesive covered plate up to the concrete.

This is a much nicer solution than trying to get fasteners into the overhead concrete. It also eliminates the possiblity of cracking and stress in the concrete that could happen from trying to drill and hammer on the concrete.